# How to show images as Carousel with first index as enable to edit?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to show images show as Carousel with first index as enable to edit.
means getting images from server and trying to show images and texts in Carousel but i have a condition
that first position(index=0) widget should be enable for edit (means should get an image from device and enter some text in their respective fields) and rest of all index should be represent the images and texts ,which are getting from the server .

Some Piece of code:

```
 Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:25),
              child: Column(
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                   FutureBuilder<MessageModel>(
                future: _messageApi.getMessagesByEventList(
                    token: widget.tokenId, 
                    eventId:  widget.eventId
                  
                  ),
              
                builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MessageModel> snapshot){
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } 
                    
                  if (snapshot.hasError){
                      return Center(child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                  }

                  return 
                  CarouselSlider.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.content.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                     
                     return Container(
                      child: Card(
                        shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100], width: 2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4 ,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data.content[index].image.fileUrl),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                                  )
                                  
                                ),
                                
                              ),
                           
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child:Text(snapshot.data.content[index].text,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color:Colors.black,
                                        fontSize:18
                                      ),
                                  )
                                 
                                )
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ),
                      ),

                    );
                    },
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.2,  
                      autoPlay: false,
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                     
                      initialPage: 1,
                    ),
                  );
                })
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

First index widget should be:

[image]

rest of index widget should shows images and text from server like:

[image]

[Video link what i achieved yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx65G.jpg)

Comment: What is your question exactly? I mean to achieve a different look for index 0 you can simply check `if (index == 0) { return anotherWidget(); } else { // your current code maybe with index -1 }`

Comment: yes tried (if index ==0  show this widget else that widget,) what you suggested to  apply only able to show 3 images but getting 4 images from the api. means zeroth index image is not showing

Comment: well you must add 1 to your itemCount: `snapshot.data.content.length + 1`

Comment: Well thank you so much, I  had solved it.